# How to use a different text in the Spinner's list than the Spinner's main text?

Tags: android

I have a `Spinner` that's used to select a sorting mode for a list (newest, oldest etc.). The entries just have the sorting mode's name (e.g. "Newest"), but when selected, I'd like the Spinner's title to use a different string (e.g. "Sorting by Newest"). Preferably the resulting string would be formatted like this:

```
String selection = ...;
String titleText = getString(R.string.spinner_title, selection);

// In strings.xml
<string name="spinner_title">Sorting by %1$s</string>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

create an `OnItemSelectedListener`() for your `Spinner`

any try this:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
   TextView selectedText = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
   if (selectedText != null) {
      selectedText.setText("YOUR TEXT HERE"); //change text when item is selected
   }
}
```

you can also change text for particular position of the `spinner`

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the TextView for the title is always the first child of the AdapterView? It seems a bit fragile to count on that.

Comment: It seems so, but will it work if the layout of the AdapterView changes?

Comment: you are using a custom spinner adapter?

Comment: Yes, although it pretty much mimics ArrayAdapter at the moment.

Comment: Still confused with the answer !!?

Comment: No, not confused. Just worried about the maintainability of this solution.